# Streamwriter, remove whole line where a specific character is found

Tags: c#, list

Maybe I'm overthinking this. I've got a working method for writing to a text file, and reading from it.

Writing:

```
public void SaveNotes()
{
    using (StreamWriter save= new StreamWriter("notes.txt", true))
    {               
        foreach (var element in collection)
        {
            spara.Write(element.Prio+ " " + element.Note+ "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to design a method that looks for any `'0'` in my list, and overwrite the entire line.

Is there any easier way to tell the program that all lines containing a `'0'` should be overwritten with blankspaces? Any input much appreciated.

```
public static void Delete(Note note)
{         
    using (StreamWriter remove = new StreamWriter("notes.txt"))
    {
        Regex rgx = new Regex("");
        foreach (var element in collection)
        {       
            while (element.Notering.Contains("0"))
            {
                rgx.Replace(element.Note, "");   
                rgx.Replace(element.Prio, "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `foreach(var element in collection.Where(c => c.Notering.Contains("0")))`?

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. Where are you looping the lines? You are not using the `StreamWriter` or a `StreamReader`, you are not using the passed argument `Note` and it's not clear what `collection` is. In general, if you want to replace/remove a line rewrite the whole file with the remaining lines.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you combine two of them?

```
public void SaveNotes()
{
    using (StreamWriter save= new StreamWriter("notes.txt", true))
    {               
        foreach (var element in collection)
        {
            if (element.Prio.IndexOf('\0') < 0 && element.Note.IndexOf('\0') < 0)
                spara.Write(element.Prio+ " " + element.Note+ "\n");
            else spara.Write(" \n");
        }
    }
}
```